# How to create Models without an app in django?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way I can create a Models.py file without creating an app and make the models work with migrations that django provides?

Comment: You can work with [*tortoise-ORM*](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this is an ORM based on Django's syntax and also works with models. It is thus designed if you want the "power" of the Django ORM but do not really want to make a web application with this.

Comment: Why no app? I don't think anything says you have to have views or anything in urls.py in an app. If I'm right (I never tried)  an app with just models and migrations  is fine.